# How to get twitter user account email using Java scribe api's

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, scribe

I am creating a twitter social login feature for my Java web application, am using the [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) library.

Following the library tutorial [here](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java) for verifying the user credentials, you will be able to retrieve the user credential as `json` object.

The retrieved `json` object doesn't have the user email, after researching for how to retrieve the email, i found [this documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) in twitter api's.

Now, translating the document with the scribe api's didn't work, and still not able to get the email.

I tried all of the following:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json");

request.addBodyParameter("include_email", "true");
//OR
request.addQuerystringParameter("include_email", "true");

service.signRequest(accessToken, request);

Response response = request.send();
String result = response.getBody();
```

Any idea how to retrieve the email using scribe will be appreciated.

**Regards**

Comment: Maybe.. just maybe, your apps is not whitelisted with twitter ?

Comment: @FerdinandNeman I don't know what exactly you mean by `"whitelisted with twitter"`.

Comment: Well, from twitter API you've provided, it says _Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter_ , means that your application must be registered with Twitter, then twitter will allow you to extract some user credential.

Comment: Ok, then do you have any idea to make my twitter app whitelisted ?

Comment: You can register your application [Here](https://apps.twitter.com/) so that your application can use Twitter's REST API.